# Stuck on uploading sketch via USB 6 pin

Tags: sketch, uploading, arduino-galileo

I'm just got a Galileo Gen2 and wanted to try a simple blinking-led. The firmware have been updated to 1.0.4. My problem is whenever I try to upload the code I get this error:

```
Sketch uses 83,775 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 10,000,000 bytes.
...
echo "Sending Command String to move to download if not already in download mode"
echo "~sketch downloadGalileo" > $tty_port_id

Deleting existing sketch on target
#Move the existing sketch on target.
echo "Deleting existing sketch on target"
"$fixed_path/lsz.exe" --escape -c "mv -f /sketch/sketch.elf /sketch/sketch.elf.old" <> $tty_port_id 1>&0
Login timed out after 60 secondsPoky 9.0.2 (Yocto Project 1.4 Reference Distro) 1.4.2 clanton /dev/ttyS1clanton login:`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply that 6-pin are not designed for uploading sketches. Instead use the micro-USB port to upload sketches.